# Timers in a .NET Website

Tags: asp.net, signalr

So I'm learning SignalR, and I like the idea of pushing changes to multiple clients. I'm building a simple monitoring site to learn with, and would like to poll a database every 10 seconds or so and push the current state of what I'm querying down to the clients. Using a timer for the "hub" object results in every client connection creating a new timer, which means that eventually all clients have their own 10-second timer, and the hub is constantly pushing down updates much more often than every 10 seconds.

I've been pushing around different ideas in my head, but wanted to make sure this isn't a simpler problem to fix than I'm making it out to be, either through SignalR or the more general problem of having one timer for the appdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried having the timer be static, or outside the hub? You can call back into the hub like so:

```
dynamic clients = Hub.GetClients<MyHub>();
```

More information on this can be found at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs towards the bottom of the page.

Basically you are having the Hub, which is per request, trying to handle something that is more global.

Comment: Excellent, I'll peruse over that. Thanks!

Comment: That was the ticket, just having a way to get at the clients in a static context.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. You don't want a timer per client, that will kill performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a great example. During demonstrations I've shown a clock running on the server, updating the clients with the server's time. I think you're saying, check something on the server and whenever it updates, inform the clients. Same sort of idea. If it helps, check out [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/bradygaster/SignalR.Demo), which is where I keep the code for those demonstrations.

Comment: Yep! With the caveat of only one master "clock" that's pushing updates instead of each client creating their own instance of the clock. I'll check out the repo, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My blog post here may help. I'm not sure how best practice the setup is so one of the SignalR guys may have to comment on that. But its an interesting example that is rather similar to what you want to be doing, I think:

http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/engineering/archive/2011/11/04/using-netadvantage-jquery-chart-infragistics-motion-framework-and-signalr-to-display-live-twitter-rates.aspx

Hope this helps!
-Graham